# C# query doesn't get executed

Tags: c#

Currently I am trying to retrieve the contents of all the entries between a specific date in a MySQL database named 'orders'. To achieve this I use the following code:

```
query = "SELECT id, date, contactinfo, orderinfo, contents, print_location, order_id, file_size FROM orders where date between " + dateFrom + " and " + dateTill + " and print_location like 'antw'";
```

dateFrom and dateTill are both variables that contains timestamps.

Everything above works perfectly. The problem that I am facing right now is that I want to check on two print_locations instead of only one. As shown in the code above I only search on 'antw'. The code that I have right now to search on two print_locations is as follows:

```
query = "SELECT id, date, contactinfo, orderinfo, contents, print_location, order_id, file_size FROM orders where date between " + dateFrom + " and " + dateTill + " and print_location like 'antw' or print_location like 'helm'";
```

But somehow this doesn't work. I don't get an error the form just freezes and making it unaccessible.

This is probably a simple issue to resolve but I can't seem to solve it. The reason why I am only showing the value of the query variable and not the rest of my code is because everything has worked fine for weeks.

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: you forgot brackets `and (print_location like 'antw' or print_location like 'helm')`

Comment: Additionally, use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). This is open to potential [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you! I never used those brackets though.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `in` operator. This is a much more readable form when you get more than 3 or 4 alternatives: `where print_location in ('antw', 'helm')`

Comment: Put `01-01-2015 and 02-01-2015; drop table orders; --` for your `dateFrom` and see how your `orders` table disappear. **Use prepared statements!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot brackets and you should use parameters to avoid injection attack

```
string Command = "SELECT id, date, contactinfo, orderinfo, contents, print_location, order_id, file_size FROM orders where date between @dateFrom  and @dateTill and (print_location like 'antw' or print_location like 'helm')";
using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command, myConnection))
    {
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dateFrom", yourDateFrom));
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dateTill", yourdateTill));
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you fubo! I will look into the parameters to avoid injection attacks.

Comment: You might also want to add a reason *why* it doesn't work properly (operator precedence rules for `or` and `and`).

Answer (score 1):

Add brackets to your logic:

```
query = "SELECT id, date, contactinfo, orderinfo, contents, print_location, order_id, file_size FROM orders where date between " + dateFrom + " and " + dateTill + " and (print_location like 'antw' or print_location like 'helm')";
```

Be careful though... this smells like a potential case of SQL injection!

Comment: This indeed was the issue. Thank you and thanks to fubo for the fast response.

Answer (score 1):

Never worked with MySQL, but maybe you're forgetting %% on your `LIKE` clauses. The way it is, it will work like `=`.

```
SELECT id, date, contactinfo, orderinfo, contents, print_location, order_id, file_size FROM orders where date between " + dateFrom + " and " + dateTill + " and (print_location like '%antw%' or print_location like '%helm%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses on your second set "OR" of conditions:

query = "SELECT id, date, contactinfo, orderinfo, contents, print_location, order_id, file_size FROM orders where date between " + dateFrom + " and " + dateTill + " and (print_location like 'antw' or print_location like 'helm')";

Otherwise, your statement reads like this:

Get me all this stuff, where date between this date and this date, and print_location like 'antw'...

Or get me all this stuff where print_location like 'helm'.

Since you're using a like, it's probably just freezing while executing your query. It would eventually finish, and you'd have way more results than you were expecting.

Also, because of injection concerns, and data modeling, you should really use a data access object model (DAO). I suggest researching it!